# Accessibility Relation for Modal Logic

Tags: logic

I have a simple question. To which accessibility relation does the modal formula $$□(P\lor \lnot P)\iff (□P\lor □\lnot P)$$ correspond? Note that this doesn’t hold for an arbitrary disjunction, but just for instances of the Principle of the Excluded Middle.

Answer (score 1):

I shall present a discussion for exclusive disjunction (*xor*, denoting it by $\underline{\vee}$). Variations on it can proceed along the same line of thought.

We want to see  what accessibility relation is required for the distributivity property of $\underline{\vee}$ over the necessity operator $\Box$ to hold and *vice versa*:

$\Box(A\underline{\vee} B)\overset{?}{\leftrightarrow}\Box A\underline{\vee}\Box B\tag{1}$

Let us record first the distributivity laws of modal operators over conjunction and disjunction (in what follows, we shall drop parentheses in accordance with the usual binding power of operators):

$\Box(A\wedge B)\leftrightarrow \Box A\wedge\Box B\tag{2}$

$\Diamond(A\wedge B)\rightarrow\Diamond A\wedge\Diamond B\tag{3}$

$\Box A\vee\Box B\rightarrow \Box(A\vee B)\tag{4}$

$\Diamond(A\vee B)\leftrightarrow\Diamond A\vee \Diamond B\tag{5}$

Notice that 3 and 4 are not reciprocal.  We shall also convert $\Box\phi$ and $\neg\Diamond\neg\phi$ to and fro by definition. Additionally, we shall use the following equivalences (referring to the convenient forms of De Morgan's laws as (7) and (8))

$A\underline{\vee} B\leftrightarrow (A\wedge\neg B)\vee(\neg A\wedge B)\tag{6}$

$A\vee B\leftrightarrow \neg(\neg A\wedge\neg B)\tag{7}$

$A\wedge B\leftrightarrow \neg(\neg A\vee\neg B)\tag{8}$

We begin with the left-to-right direction of (1). Invoking (6), we shall try to derive eventually

$\Box(A\underline{\vee} B)\rightarrow (\Box A\wedge\neg\Box B)\vee(\neg\Box A\wedge\Box B)\tag{$\ast$}$

We rewrite the antecedent of $\ast$:

$\rightarrow\Box((A\wedge\neg B)\vee(\neg A\wedge B))\tag{by 6}$

$\rightarrow\Box\neg(\neg(A\wedge\neg B)\wedge\neg(\neg A\wedge B))\tag{by 7}$

$\rightarrow\neg\Diamond(\neg(A\wedge\neg B)\wedge\neg(\neg A\wedge B))\tag{by definition}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\Diamond\neg(A\wedge\neg B)\wedge\Diamond\neg(\neg A\wedge B))\tag{by 3}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\neg\Box(A\wedge\neg B)\wedge\neg\Box(\neg A\wedge B))\tag{by definition}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\neg(\Box A\wedge\Box\neg B)\wedge\neg(\Box\neg A\wedge\Box B))\tag{by 2}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\neg(\Box A\wedge\neg\Diamond B)\wedge\neg(\neg\Diamond A\wedge\Box B))\tag{by definition}$

$\rightarrow(\Box A\wedge\neg\Diamond B)\vee(\neg\Diamond A\wedge\Box B)\tag{$\ast\ast$}$

Comparing $\ast$ and $\ast\ast$, we see that we need to stipulate the accessibility relation $R$ so that $\Box\phi\leftrightarrow\Diamond\phi$ holds in order to obtain $\ast$. Actually, we need $\Diamond\phi\rightarrow\Box\phi$ at this stage.

By the requirements of possible worlds semantics for $\Box$ and $\Diamond$, this is possible only if  $R$ is a functional (univalent) relation: For each $w$, there is exactly one $w′$ such that $wRw′$. Hence

$$\forall w_{i}\forall w_{j}\forall w_{k}(w_{i}Rw_{j}\wedge w_{i}Rw_{k}\rightarrow w_{j} = w_{k})$$

Notice that a particular instance satisfying this requirement is that $R$ is a reflexive identity relation. So, we turn to right-to-left direction of (1). Invoking (6), we shall try to derive eventually

$\Box A\underline{\vee}\Box B\rightarrow\Box((A\wedge\neg B)\vee(\neg A\wedge B))\tag{$\dagger$}$

We rewrite the antecedent of $\dagger$:

$\rightarrow((\Box A\wedge\neg\Box B)\vee(\neg\Box A\wedge\Box B))\tag{by 6}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\neg\Box A\vee\neg\neg\Box B)\vee\neg(\neg\neg\Box A\vee\neg\Box B))\tag{by 8}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\neg\Box A\vee\Box B)\vee\neg(\Box A\vee\neg\Box B)\tag{double negation elimination}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\Diamond\neg A\vee\Box B)\vee\neg(\Box A\vee\Diamond\neg B))\tag{by definition}$

$\rightarrow\neg(\Diamond\neg A\vee\Diamond B)\vee\neg(\Diamond A\vee\Diamond\neg B)\tag{by $\Box\phi\leftrightarrow\Diamond\phi$}$

$\rightarrow\neg\Diamond(\neg A\vee B)\vee\neg\Diamond(A\vee\neg B))\tag{by 5}$

$\rightarrow\Box\neg(\neg A\vee B)\vee\Box\neg(A\vee\neg B)\tag{by definition}$

$\rightarrow\Box(A\wedge\neg B)\vee\Box(\neg A\wedge B)\tag{by 8}$

$\rightarrow\Box((A\wedge\neg B)\vee (\neg A\wedge B))\tag{by 2}$

We have derived $\dagger$, employing $\Box\phi\leftrightarrow\Diamond\phi$ in between.  It should be remarked that the two stages of (1) are not symmetrical. We need $\Box\phi\rightarrow\Diamond\phi$ at the second stage. Therefore, it is sufficient that $R$ is serial, i.e., $\forall w\exists w'(wRw')$. However, such details seem too much of a digression for one question.

Comment: I’ve realized that this trivially boils down to the axiom CD which defines a functional frame relation. Also, note that ~♢(P&Q) doesn’t imply (~♢P&~♢Q). However, the converse does hold. 

Im pretty sure I had a brain fart when I posted this since it’s obviously just the CD axiom.